# Linq sobre dictionary c#

Tags: c#, linq, diccionarios

estoy intentando hacer un linq sobre un diccionario para encontrar una key, tengo algo como esto, y quisera encontrar el valor de la key "Hola":

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string> Datos = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> Dato = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dato.Add("Hola","Mundo");
Datos.Add(1,Dato);
```

Comment: Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> Datos = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary<string, string> Dato = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dato.Add("Hola","Mundo");
            Datos.Add(1,Dato);

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Usa el boton [edit] para arreglar la pregunta. Usa CTRL+k para formatear el codigo ;)

Comment: Es sencillo lo que quieres. Has intentado algo? un simple `.Where` debe darte lo que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Si buscas la key de Datos que contiene el diccionario con la llave "Hola":

```
var query = (from x in Datos
             where x.Value.Keys.Contains("Hola")
             select x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

O si te gusta mas en versión fluent:

```
var query = Datos
    .Where(x => x.Value.Keys.Contains("Hola"))
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Si por el contrario, si buscas el valor del diccionario Dato que contiene la key "Hola", no ocupas Linq:

```
var key = Dato["Hola"];
```

o si no estas seguro de que exista la clave "Hola":

```
string valor;
if (Dato.TryGetValue("Hola", out valor))
{
    // aquí puedes usar valor
}
```

Comment: No es exacta esta respuesta, ya que el OP quiere el valor y no la clave. Por otra parte, es mejor esperar a que se especifique por parte del op qué ha intentado antes de responder.

Comment: Pues no tiene sentido, lo lógico es que busque la llave del diccionario Datos teniendo una llave del diccionario Dato, eso es lo que entendí a la primera que leí su pregunta. Ni siquiera requiere linq para eso, un simple Dato["Hola"] (o Dato.TryGetValue). Lo lógico es que, si está pidiendo linq, y pone dos diccionarios donde uno contiene al otro, no es porque quiera el valor del primer diccionario dando la llave del mismo diccionario.

Comment: _tengo algo como esto, y quisera encontrar el valor de la key "Hola":_ dice _el valor_ pero puede que tengas razón y sea la clave. De todas maneras, por eso digo que es mejor esperar a que el OP lo aclare todo antes de responder :)

Comment: ¿si agrego la otra respuesta (por ejemplo, si realmente quiere el valor de la key "hola") estará bien?

Comment: Con editar esta supongo que valdría. Pero lo ideal sería que el Op aclarase que es exactamente lo que necesita

Comment: Están ya las dos opciones, a ver cuál de las dos es la que le sirve.